# Should I pronounce 'e' in forte?

Tags: pronunciation, silent-letter

Could anyone explain why *forte* (*music: in loud manner*) is pronounced with *e*, but *taste* is pronounced with a silent *e*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**forte** actually comes with two different pronunciations, though many people confuse the two in terms of how to use them.

**forte**, used to mean a strength or strong point, meaning originates from the French word *fort*, meaning 'strong'. The correct pronunciation of forte in this context is *fort*.

**forte**, as used as a direction in music to mean loud, originates from the Italian word *forte*, meaning 'strong'. The correct pronunciation of forte in this context is *for·te*.

That being said, most people don't make this distinction and pronounce it for·te for all contexts, both the 'strong point' sense as well as the musical term.

As to why the e is pronounced in forte, but not in taste, well as the examples above show, English borrowed heavily from many languages throughout the course of time, and the rules of pronunciation of the source language still resonate to this day.

The word **taste** has evolved from the Old French word *tast* (noun), or *taster* (verb) ‘touch, try, taste,’ and the pronunciation still prevails.

> [image: screenshot: Google definition of taste]

Comment: So it's possible that words with same spelling to have different pronunciations. Is there any particular term we call that so I can search it on internet?

Comment: @user178049: It is indeed possible - they are called **homographs** -words spelled the same but not necessarily pronounced the same and have different meanings and origins. *bow* (as in bow tie), and *bow* (to bend at the waist) would be another well known example. As are *wind* (moving air) and *wind* (to wind an alarm clock).

Comment: Ahh, I guess I've learnt that but I forgot. Anyway, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I believe another reason why 'the strong point' is pronounced with the _e_, is to differentiate it from the English word fort. It would otherwise not always be evident that one is using a loan word.

Comment: @user178049 I'm afraid it's not just possible, but surprisingly common in English!